# QuickBlox. iOS. The change you wanted was rejected (422)

Tags: ios, facebook, quickblox

1) I filled in the Admin Panel "App Id" and "secret".

2) Facebook app I created.

Window appears with authorization. Next, i fill there fields and i click on button "Log in" and appears next error:

https://vk.com/doc25528065_344157930
https://vk.com/doc25528065_344157302

And don't disappear this the window with authorization.

```
 Error: The change you wanted was rejected (422).
```

Facebook app:
[vk.com/doc25528065_344158798](http://vk.com/doc25528065_344158798), [vk.com/doc25528065_344158827](http://vk.com/doc25528065_344158827)

Comment: Did you at least Google for "error 422"? Wikipedia explains all the status code. This one: Server says your request is syntactically fine, but semantically wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729, yes, i read this. I see, what it simply won't let that data be processed. If i understand correctly, I don't understand why. Example me, please.

Comment: I decided the problem.